Прямая речь или нет? (4)
Если не можешь отказать, то скажи ему «а ты приходи завтра».
Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении?
И можно объяснить расстановку знаков. Как называется этот вид речи?

Чужое высказывание может передаваться прямой и косвенной речью.
Прямая речь передает слова говорящих буквально (без изменения формы) и заключается в кавычки.
Когда прямая речь находится после слов автора, то перед ней ставится двоеточие и первое слово в прямой речи пишется с прописной буквы.

При передаче чужих слов в прямой речи обращения, междометия, вводные слова сохраняются, а в косвенной речи они опускаются.

● Так что, думаю, правильно нужно написать так:
Если не можешь отказать, то скажи ему: «А ты приходи завтра».
Можно и восклицательный знак поставить («А ты приходи завтра!»).

Косвенная речь — это способ передачи чужой речи, при котором воспроизводится только содержание высказывания, без сохранения его лексических, синтаксических и стилистических особенностей.
Синтаксически косвенная речь представляет собой сложноподчинённое предложение, где в главном предложении передаются слова автора, а в придаточном — само высказывание.

• В этом случае предложение будет таким (кавычки и восклицательный знак уже не используются):
Если не можешь отказать, то скажи ему, чтобы он приходил завтра.
Таким образом, прямая речь передаёт высказывание другого лица дословно, сохраняя его форму, в то время как косвенная речь —  только его содержание, встраивая в авторское повествование.
В ответе использованы материалы из статьи "Способы передачи чужой речи. Прямая и косвенная речь".
С подробнейшей информацией о прямой речи можно ознакомиться в справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя (Знаки препинания при прямой речи).

Это  вариант оформления дословного высказывания, когда отсутствует предупредительная пауза, обозначенная двоеточием:
Если не можешь отказать, то скажи ему «а ты приходи завтра».
Стиль разговорный. В этом случае прямая речь занимает позицию члена предложения и естественным образом вписывается в его структуру.
ПРЯМАЯ РЕЧЬ КАК ЧЛЕН ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ (подлежащее, дополнение, несогласованное определение)
(1) Нераспространенная прямая речь может являться членом 
предложения – подлежащим, дополнением, несогласованным 
определением.
(2) В этом случае прямая речь не имеет собственной интонации 
и вписывается в структуру всего предложения. 
(3) Прямая речь заключается в кавычки, но двоеточие перед 
ней не ставится.
(4) Допускается использование как прописной, так и строчной 
буквы в начале прямой речи.

В заданном предложении прямая речь является дополнением: скажи (что?).
Розенталь, § 51
Примечание. Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в 
текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются 
кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); 
Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет 
где-то в избе», всё больше собирало сторонников (Ф.); Он 
вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного 
не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком 
«Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.


Про цитируемый текст в самом начале: зачем жирным выделять, и даже точку. Её-то за что? Тем не менее — плюс.

Это у меня "эстетика" такая:  выделяю шрифтом значимые части. А точка случайно под раздачу попала. Спасибо за голос)

М-м... Sharon, мне думается, что вариант оформления не может быть разговорным. Разговорным может быть высказывание.

Благодарю за внимание, неточность исправлена. Кстати, вы считаете классическое (книжное) оформление прямой речи единственно правильным? Как-то странно выглядит такая запись в сетевой переписке.
